# Any reason to NOT turn on keep alive?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

With Nginx acting as a reverse proxy and with SSL on, is there any reason to not turn on keep alive, especially if traffic is bursty (i.e. a user makes 10 requests in 20 seconds)? Specifically, are there any concerns regarding atomic transactions or security?

For example, a request to a server gets handled, modifies the database, but the API machine times out for some reason. Then the same client with thte same signature gets sent to Nginx but is processed to a different API box, and the same exact database modification happens, so it happens twice. Is something like atomic transactions even relevant to keep alive, or is that more relevant to application code?

Any security downsides?

Comment: The short answer to your question is NO there are no security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Keepalive has no influence over application security, atomicity of the request, or anything even close to that - it is at a much higher level.

HTTP keepalive simply allows clients to re-use a connection to make more HTTP requests, so you can have:

```
open socket
make http request
make http request
...
close socket
```

Rather than

```
open socket
make http request
close socket
open socket
make http request
close socket
...
```

Your application receives the HTTP requests in exactly the same way, whether KA is on or off.

Wikipedia has a great list of advantages/disadvantages of using the feature: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

> #### Advantages
>
> - Less CPU and memory usage (because fewer connections are open simultaneously).
> - Enables HTTP pipelining of requests and responses.
> - Reduced network congestion (fewer TCP connections).
> - Reduced latency in subsequent requests (no handshaking).
> - Errors can be reported without the penalty of closing the TCP connection.

Comment: In HTTP/1.1 protocol, this is automatic w/o having to specify any keepalive directive.  However, in HTTP/1.0 this is basically something build over the protocol and not in the specification for the protocol.

Comment: So there shouldn't be any issue such as duplicating database transactions or anything like that. That's all at the app level, right?

Comment: Absolutely right :-)

Comment: If this answered, your question, could you please mark it as answered?